# unable to understand the error in lex program to count no of tokens

Tags: lex

i wrote the lex program to calculate the count of tokens using gedit in linux. but it is not running.i m new in this. also i m not able to find out the problem in the code.

this is the program code :

```
    count=0
digit [0-9]
letter [A-Z][a-z]
%%
{letter} | ({letter}|{digit})* 
count++
%%
int main()
{
yylex()
printf("no. of identifier=%d",count);
}
```

error msg is :

```
    scanner.l:9: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘yylex’
scanner.l:10: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
```

Comment: upvote the answer that helped you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialization in the [Definitions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Definitions-Section.html) section of your lex spec isn't quite right.  It should be a syntactically correct C statement, indented.  Also, your code to increment `count` [must be on the same line](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Rules-Section.html) as the pattern it goes with.  So you want something like this:

```
    int count = 0;
digit [0-9]
letter [A-Z][a-z]
%%
{letter}|({letter}|{digit})*    count++; 
%%
int main()
{
    yylex();
    printf("no. of identifier=%d",count);
}
```